# Extract first and last occurence of a group of numbers by ignoring certain elements

Tags: java, regex

Need to get the first occurence and the last one from a line of numbers by ignoring a certain element.

E.g. from `00 44 88 45 00 25 78 46 00 46 58 00` I need to extract `44` and `58` (ignoring all occurences of `00`).

The code I am using:

```
  final Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(?!00)(\\d{2})(\\s)(.*)(?!00)(\\d{2})" );
  final Matcher m = p.matcher( "00 44 88 45 00 25 78 46 00 46 58 00" );
  final String first = m.replaceAll( "$1" );
  final String last = m.replaceAll( "$4" );

  System.out.println( "first = " + first );
  System.out.println( "last = " + last );
```

Console output:

```
first = 00 44 00
last = 00 58 00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fixing current approach

You can fix your approach like this:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "^(?:00(?:\\s+00)*\\s+)?(\\d{2})(.*?)(\\d{2})(?:\\s+00(?:\\s+00)*)?$" );
final Matcher m = p.matcher( "00 44 88 45 00 25 78 46 00 46 58 00" );
final String first = m.replaceAll( "$1" );
final String last = m.replaceAll( "$3" );
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/httUN5).

## Extracting approach

Alternatively, you may extract the values without replacing:

```
^(?:00(?:\s+00)*\s+)?(\d{2})|(\d{2})(?:\s+00(?:\s+00)*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EmRaId/2). Grab Group 1 and 2 values.

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/QJojyL):

```
String s = "00 44 88 45 00 25 78 46 00 46 58 00";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:00(?:\\s+00)*\\s+)?(\\d{2})|(\\d{2})(?:\\s+00(?:\\s+00)*)?$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
    }
    if (matcher.group(2) != null)  {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
44
58
```

## Splitting with filtering approach

Also, you may simply split the string with whitespaces, remove all `00` items and get the first and last items:

```
String s = "00 44 88 45 00 25 78 46 00 46 58 00";
List<String> result = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+"))
       .filter(i -> !i.equals("00"))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result.get(0));                // => 44
System.out.println(result.get(result.size()-1));  // => 58
```

See [this Java demo](http://ideone.com/wVwVko).

Comment: I need to use replaceAll() method of the matcher.

Comment: @Mary2349 I added your fixed solution to the top of the answer